# Make a small HTML application update a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, require

I want to make a local HTML application read and update a JSON file and use its content to display HTML content. Alas, I'm stuck at the very first step, as I can't seem to setup any sort of test file that simply notices and reads a JSON file. From what I see online, I need to use other libraries. I attempted to use require.js but I can't make it work and the documentation doesn't help me.

I imported the require.js with a  tag and attempt to launch something out of what I got from the documentation, but there's nothing to do. It doesn't look like it's willing to take .json files.

```
requirejs([
   'example'
], function(example) {
   const config = require('./config.json')
});
```

My issue is to get the program to read the file. From there I believe I can make the display of it, but this JS thing is all alien to me.

Comment: _a local HTML application_

You mean a web site? 

Comment: For security reasons, JS running in the browser cannot read or write arbitrary files. So a local HTML app that is supposed to read/write JSON can only do so indirectly; the user would have to pick the file using an `<input type="file">`, then download the changed version and save it over the existing file. JS running like a regular programming language (i.e. in the `node` environment) can do that just fine though. To create a HTML based app with node you need [electron](https://electronjs.org/) though.

Comment: @ChrisG He can run Chrome with `-–allow-file-access-from-files` though (or the equivalent flag in another browser). Since this is just for personal use, it would be a viable option.

Comment: @Mohrn True, in the end it'll depend on whether OP is willing to learn the "proper" way, i.e. running a local web server.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way would be to run a web server or use something like Electron and build a desktop app (as @chrisG points out in the comments). But if you wanna do this in the browser without an web server you could do something like:

1. Run Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` (or however you allow local file access in your browser of choice)
2. [Put your JSON in a js file and load it](https://codepen.io/a-morn/pen/XvZgNR) (to just do this you don't need the flag, but if you want to use absolute path you'll need it)